# Running a Python command to ssh to a computer and run MATLAB on that computer

Tags: python, matlab, ssh

I am trying to run this command in Python3.  Each part separately works correctly, but I cannot get them to work together.

```py
os.system('ssh -t user@computer \'cd /MatLabFolder; /Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r \"cd /Test; try, run(\'/Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m\'); end; quit\"; bash -l\'')
```

For now `TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m` just has the following in it

```matlab
in_dir_list={'/Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/Test/58514_TF03_default','/Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/Test/58514_TF03_mask10'};
out_dir_list={'/Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/Test/58514_TF03_default','/Volumes/promiseraid9/workspace/colleen/NewResiduals/Test/58514_TF03_mask10'};
in_dir_list
```

Basically I'm just having it print out what `in_dir_list` is, just so that I can see it is working.

Now if I am already `ssh`'d onto the computer I want to process on, and run

```sh
/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/bin/matlab -r "cd /Test; try, run('/Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m'); end; quit"
```

it runs as it should.  So I know the UNIX command is correct. 
But if I run the first command, MATLAB is not recognizing the `"  \'  "` like Python does, and is just eliminating the `'` all together so the command that gets run in MATLAB ends up being

```
cd /Test; try, run(/Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m); end; quit
                    |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

Notice no `'` before and after the M-file and path.

I also know the ssh command is also correct, because running it up until the point of running a command in MATLAB also works (meaning I can ssh to the computer, and open up MATLAB). And it attempts to run the command at least, but because of the `"  '\  "` confusion, it doesn't see the needed `'`.

How do I properly escape the quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping quotes through multiple shells is a nightmare. In principle you should escape both the `\` and the `'` characters, leading to `\\\'`:

```
run(\\\'/Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m\\\')
```

But it depends on which shells are used, and how these parse the strings, what the exact combination of escape characters and quotes you end up with.

A simpler solution is to avoid the quotes altogether. In MATLAB,

```matlab
run('/Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m')
```

is the same as

```matlab
run Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m
```

The latter doesn't require quotes, as long as there are no spaces in the file name.

Comment: Excellent, that worked run Test/TF03_MatLabCommands_and_results.m Thank you so very much!!